# Compare and update dictionary?

Tags: python

I created two list of dictionaries

```
dict1 = [
    {'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'old_qty':100}, {'name':'Grape','lot':456,'old_qty':20}
] 

dict2 = [
    {'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'new_qty':50}, {'name':'Grape','lot':456,'new_qty':30}
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'old_qty':100, 'new_qty':50}, {'name':'Grape','lot':456,'old_qty':20,'new_qty':30}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what did you try? what logic?

Comment: Look up comprehensions, `zip`, and merging dictionaries.

Comment: I am trying to get the quantity of a product before and after of a date. I wrote 2 SQL queries and stored in two dictionaries. Now i need to update the first dictionary with value from dictionary 2.

Comment: you will probably want to use [dict.update](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) but note that you certainly can get the old quantity and the new one with one SQL query

Comment: @Tryph, could you give me any example, that will be very helpful.

Comment: *Note you are labeling `lists` as `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
result = [] 
for i,j in zip(dict1, dict2):
    i.update(j)
    result.append(i)
```

the result would be your desired one.

Comment: what if dict1 will not in the same sequence as second?

Comment: That's why I wrote maybe, the question's logic is a little unclear.@BearBrown

Comment: so i think you shoud not to do the answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to merge two dicts that share a name, try this:

```
dict1 = [{'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'old_qty':100},{'name':'Grape','lot':456,'old_qty':20}]
dict2 = [{'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'new_qty':50},{'name':'Grape','lot':456,'new_qty':30}]

z = []
common_attr = 'name'
for d1 in dict1:
    for d2 in dict2:
        if d1[common_attr] == d2[common_attr]:
            z.append({**d1, **d2})
print(z)
```

If you mean to use another logic for merging, this code snippet could still be helpful.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @KbiR Then my question is that do you need those items that don't share any data?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this perhaps (considering values of the keys `name` and `lot` can uniquely identify a dictionary from other):

```
dict1 = [{'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'old_qty':100},{'name':'Grape','lot':456,'old_qty':20}]
dict2 = [{'name':'Apple','lot':1234,'new_qty':50},{'name':'Grape','lot':456,'new_qty':30}]

dict3 = [d1 for d1 in dict1 for d2 in dict2 if d1["name"]==d2["name"] if d1["lot"]==d2["lot"] if not d1.update(d2)]

print(dict3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some layering of `for` loops

```
listc = lista[:] 

for i in listb:
    for j in listc:
        if i['name'] == j['name']:
            for x in i:
                if x not in j.keys():
                    j[x] = i[x]

print(listc)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 dicta_comp.py 
> [{'name': 'Apple', 'lot': 1234, 'old_qty': 100, 'new_qty': 50}, {'name': 'Grape', 'lot': 456, 'old_qty': 20, 'new_qty': 30}]
> ```